# How to retrieve the maximum width of multiple <input> elements with the same class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, max, width

I have five input elements with different widths, but all of them share the same class, for example, class="c1".

I am looking for a way to use jQuery to retrieve the maximum width among them. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you.

Comment: I edited your question. If the edit isn't correct, please let me know.

Comment: it is ok . thanks Erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping through each element and checking for each element's width is greater than the next one and storing the maximum width in a variable to make sure that the current width is greater than the previous.
Here's an example code snippet that should work

```
let maxWidth = 0;
$('.c1').each(function() {
    const elWidth = $(this).width();
    if(elWidth > maxWidth){
        maxWidth = elWidth;
    }
});
console.log('Max width', maxWidth)
```

Hope you find this useful :)